# Table header background-image and sorting arrow images

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

I've been using jquery.tablesorter to sort my tables, but I'd like to give my table headers a pattern by using a background-image. If I do it that way, the .headerSortUp and .headerSortDown class on sorted cell(s) overwrite the background-image on those cells.

I read CSS3 supports multiple backgrounds, but what is the best way to use both a background-image and have sort arrows/images?

My thoughts were to

- Make images that have both the pattern and the arrows (doesn't seem very elegant)
- Add a div or span to each th and apply the sort class to that instead of the th

Any advice would be appreciated. Actually, jqGrid is a good example of what I'm looking for. Maybe I should just buy that.

Thanks.

Comment: jqGrid comes with MIT license, does it not? Why do you need to buy it? You can buy support hours as a token of appreciation, of course. I would go with div in each th.

Comment: Maybe is used to. Now it's only a 30 license. 
http://www.trirand.net/licensing.aspx

Comment: jqGrid Client is still under MIT license (see their google code site). PHP or .NET stack is proprietary with varying pricing.

Comment: Check my Pure CSS answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22222257/2195518 (possible duplicate)

Answer (score 0):

Inserting an empty div into the `<th>` tag and applying the sort class should give you a quick clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably get away with setting the table headers to `position: relative` and use `::before` set to `display: block; position: absolute; top,left,right,bottom: 0;` to apply the bg you want. This way you don't have to keep a separate version of the jquery ui css with your custom changes in it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Pure CSS solution:

```
.headerSortDown:after,
.headerSortUp:after{
    content: ' ';
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
    border: 8px solid transparent;
}
.headerSortDown:after{
    top: 10px;
    border-top-color: silver;
}
.headerSortUp:after{
    bottom: 15px;
    border-bottom-color: silver;
}
```

[Also check my JSFiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/rTXXz/2/) http://jsfiddle.net/rTXXz/2/